# Why ArrayBuffer is deleted after RDD transform?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, backend, rdd

Here is my scala code:

```
  var calcUsers = new ArrayBuffer[Int]()
  nRDD.foreach(item=>{
    val arr = item.split(' ')
    val currUserId = arr(1).toInt
    calcUsers.+=(currUserId)
    println("calcUsers",currUserId,calcUsers.length)
  })
  println("calcUsers",calcUsers)
```

In the first `println`, calcUsers's length is increased as it processes.

But in the second line, output always is 0.

Why? How to solve it?

Comment: From the use of the word `RDD` , I am assuming this is Spark. You can not use variables in Spark (i.e. `var`) Spark creates a copy of the variable for the worker when it serializes the function. In the last print, you are printing on the `master` where no work has been done

Comment: @sinanspd Okay But I still have no idea how to solve it. T.T

Comment: Don't use mutation. `map` the RDD with the functionality you want and then `collect` at the master before printing

Comment: @sinanspd  `val calcUsers = new ArrayBuffer[Int]()
      val userList = nRDD.map(item=>{
        val arr = item.split(' ')
        val currUserId = arr(1).toInt
        calcUsers.+=(currUserId)
        currUserId
      }).distinct()
      userList.collect()
      println("calcUsers",calcUsers)
      println("userList",userList.count())` I used `map` and `collect` here. Is it correct?

Comment: Changing the `val` to `var` doesn't make a difference. The point is you should not be updating anything outside of the lexical scope of the function. `calcUsers` simply can not live outside of the function you are passing into `map` . So you have to take your entire RDD and transform into the final result of the `calcUsers` you want to see

Comment: i.e. `val calcUsers = RDD.map(_.split(' ')(1).toIntOption)` This code is still not safe, you aren't guarenteed an element but I will leave it up to you to complete this and to deal with the resulting `Option`. Then you can do `calcUsers.collect()` in the Master in order to be able to print

Comment: @sinanspd Thank you so much. I temporariy solved it by your method. And I need to learn more about why.

Comment: RDD's is a disctributed data structure. The RDD actually does not live on the driver node (the node on which your code is actually running). All RDD operations (map, foreach) etc are actually performed on the executor nodes. So, Spark creates a closure of the operating function (you can think of it as an object containing the copies of all required variables and the function itself) and sends this object to each executor node, where it execute on the actual RDD.

Comment: In simpler words, Spark will create multiple copies of your `calcUsers` and will send it to executor nodes along with the function. Each executor will then execute the function using their own copy of `calcUsers`. The `calcUser` which you are seeing here will not be used at all.